# Scrapy: Get text between two identifiers

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have the following HTML that I am parsing using Scrapy:

```
<TD CLASS="dddefault">
    <SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Associated Term: </SPAN>Fall 2015 - Qatar 
    <BR>
    <SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Registration Dates: </SPAN>Apr 09, 2015 to Aug 27, 2015 
    <BR>
    <SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Levels: </SPAN>Graduate, Undergraduate 
    <BR>
</TD>
```

I want to get stuff like the term which is between the first SPAN and BR and the date which is between the second SPAN and BR.

I tried this:

```
term = response.xpath('//td[@class="dddefault"]/span[@class="fieldlabeltext"][1]/following-sibling::text()').extract()

date = response.xpath('//td[@class="dddefault"]/span[@class="fieldlabeltext"][2]/following-sibling::text()').extract()
```

But these give me the text for everything below it as well.

Is there any way I can get the text after the SPAN and before the BR?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way I can get the text after the SPAN and before the BR?

the *'after SPAN'* part criteria is easy to implement since the SPAN being current context node, but *'before the BR'* part may not be as easy as you think because there are multiple `BR` elements in your HTML sample (f.e `Graduate, Undergraduate` will also be considered before `BR`, the 3rd `BR`).

So, I'd suggest a different approach, by using XPath position index `[1]` to limit the result to the nearest following-sibling text node, which will return the expected text nodes, for example :

```
//td[@class="dddefault"]/span[@class="fieldlabeltext"][1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
//td[@class="dddefault"]/span[@class="fieldlabeltext"][2]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```